# an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine Docker

Tags: installation, docker, boot2docker

I am just a newbie starting to learn Docker.

Before I even start learning something, I am having some difficulty installing it. I'm following the documentation at http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows

The problem is basically as the title says. I enabled virtualization tool though BIOS and I could see Docker is installed in my Windows 8.1.

But when I tried

```
$docker version
```

it shows me the following error message:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version <Client> go1.4.2
Git commit <Client> 786b29d
OS/Arch <Client>: windows/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://~ :an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what error message? How have you installed docker on your Windows host?

Comment: Using VM. The error message is the title of my question...

Comment: what VM solution? VirtualBox, Hyper-V, vmware?

Comment: and what operating system did you choose for that VM? (OS + version + kernel version)

Comment: I downloaded it from
docs.docker.com/installation/windows

Comment: have your run the _"Boot2Docker Start"_ shortcut? and what does `docker version` show?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. It's clearer now. And yes, I have run the Boot2Docker Start shortcut and the Client version is 1.7.1 but the error message still shows up.

Comment: you mean the error message shows up when you run `docker version`? or do you have any other output to share with us?

Comment: The error message shows up at the end when I ran >docker version.

Comment: could you edit your question with the full content of the output of `docker version`

Comment: I'm afraid your issue is not a programming problem and is too broad to fit this website rules. Your issue is either that your docker engine is not running, or your VM is not running or you have a firewall or antivirus preventing the docker client to connect to the docker engine in the VM. Focus your effort on reinstalling those taking care that at each step there are no error

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue on version 1.8 and windows 8.1, with this command and docker run hello-world. Did you find how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same error. I reinstalled and stuff started to breaks... I was able to fix my issue by deleting the vm in virtualbox and deleting my .docker folder in my home directory. I hope this helps other :)